Contact Form 7 CiviCRM integration, how to retrieve the defaults
I have CiviCRM 5.73.4 and WP 6.5.4.
In WP i did load the Plugins "Contact Form 7" and "Contact Form 7 CiviCRM integration".
In the Settings of "Contact Form 7 CiviCRM integration" i get a "Validation successful" for the Integration to the local civiCRM.
In civiCRM i designed a Form with FormProcessor to update existing contact data.
On the "Try out"-Tab it does work like expected.
But i can not connect the Form in WP to the backend.
No Data from the Form is received, processed in the backend, and also the retrived data do not show up in the Webform.
Is there a syntax I have to embbed in the Formfields, like
[email* email default:user_email]
which only reads the mailadress from the wp-database.
Any help is welcome!
